# Automorphism group of the quantum Weyl field

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, automorphism-groups

Let $\mathsf{k}$ be a field with zero characteristic, and $q \in \mathsf{k}$ a non-zero elemento which is not a root of unit. The quantum plane $\mathsf{k}_q[x,y]$ is the algebra given by generators $x,y$ and relation $yx=qxy$.

The deformation by a paramater $q$ has a strong impact on the automorphism group of this algebra.
Let's compare, for instance, with the case of the polynomial algebra $\mathsf{k}[x,y]$. Its automorphism group has a classical description by Jung and van der Kulk: it is the amalgamated product of the group of affine automorphisms and Jonquèries automorphisms over their interesection. So automorphism group is 'big' (in fact it is and ind-scheme as shown by Shafarevich).

The automorphisms group of $\mathsf{k}_q[x,y]$, on the other hand, is 'small': it is isomorphic to the torus $\mathsf{k}^{*2}$, as shown by J. Alev and M. Chamarie.

The quantum plane is a Noetherian domain, hence it admits a skew field of fractions $\mathsf{k}_q(x,y)$, usually called the quantum Weyl field.

Now, I've heard from some specialists that, despite $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathsf{k}\mathsf{k}_q[x,y]$ being small, the automorphism group of the quantum Weyl field is isomorphic to the Cremona group $\operatorname{Birat}(\mathsf{k}^2)$.

In my opinion there should be no surprise in the fact the automorphism group become much more complex when we go to the level of skew field of fractions. This is well known for instance for the first Weyl algebra.

However, I find very surprising that the automorphism group of the quantum Weyl field should be isomorphic to the Cremona group.

I think this result is folklore. But anyway, is there any reference for this?