# Automorphism group of the first Weyl field

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, invariant-theory, automorphism-groups

A related question is this one ([Automorphism group of the quantum Weyl field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444254/automorphism-group-of-the-quantum-weyl-field)).

Let $A_1$ denote the rank 1 Weyl algebra (over the complex numbers), and $D_1$ its skew field of fractions, called the first Weyl field.

What is known about the group of (algebra) automorphisms of $D_1$?

Of course, every automorphism of $A_1$ induces an automorphism of $D_1$. The struture of the automorphism group of $A_1$ is well-known (by Makar-Limanov), and its finite subgroups of automorphisms are classified (they are, up to conjugation, the finite subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2$). However, besides these automorphisms, very little is known. The last work I've seen on the subject is due to Alev and Dumas and it is more than twenty years old. A remarkable open problem is: are there autormophisms of $D_1$ that are not induced form $A_1$ and have finite order?

One of the reasons for knowing the automorphism group of $D_1$ is to study its invariant subrings. This is usually called the Noncommutative Noether's Problem, and has been studied by some ring theorists by its own sake and due to its connection to diverse variations of the Gelfand-Kirillov Conjecture.

Another reason to study subrings of invariants $D_1^G$, where $G$ is a finite group, is the following. The famous conjecture by Artin states that very few division rings can appear as  "function fields" of noncommutative surfaces, and he has given a finite list of possibilities.

$D_1$ is one of the division rings on that list. One can show (with some non-trivial effort) that the Gelfand-Kirillov transcendence degree of $D_1^G$ is the same as the Gelfand-Kirillov transcendence degree of $D_1$ (namely, $2$). So its reasonable to suppose that $D_1^G$ is again a division ring on Artin's list.

In fact, many results scattered in the literatura indicates that, if $D_1^G$ is on that list, it should *again* be $D_1$ (for instance, $D_1^G$ cannot be the division ring of fractions of the quantum plane, neither a division algebra finite dimensional of its center of transcendence degree 2, neither the division ring of fractions of the ring of differential operators on a curve of positive genus, etc). Indeed, in all known cases, $D_1^G \simeq D_1$.

Hence, I am curious to know what is the current knowledge on the automorphism group of $D_1$. References to research papers are preferable, but I am also interested in any 'folklore' result as well.